# Error while Verifying OpenSSL Timestamp Response

Tags: openssl, timestamp

Good morning. I'm having a weird issue while verifying a response from a TSA (TimeStamping Authority). I'm using the [TimeStamping Service from the ERMIS Gateway](http://www.yap.gov.gr/index.php/aped/timestamping-service.html) (Hellenic Public Administration). I use openssl to generate a TS Query. After that, with CURL, I send it over to the TS server, and it responds back.

I'm using the [guide over at Digistamp](https://www.digistamp.com/technical/software-alternatives/using-openssl-to-request-timestamps/?q=1), following the same steps. The only thing that's changed is the OID Policy, as the ERMIS Gateway prompts you to do:

[image]

The server responds with an actual response, that I'm trying to verify (It doesn't throw any errors, or anything).

During verification, the following comes up (the `text.txt` file contains a simple hello world message):
[image]

Comment: Welcome to InfoSec.SE! Please consider replacing those screenshots with the appropriately marked up text version. This makes it more mobile friendly, doesn't rely on external ressources and makes the question indexable for the actual error messages.